# numpy recarray append_fields: can't append numpy array of datetimes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, recarray

I have a recarray containing various fields and I want to append an array of datetime objects on to it.

However, it seems like the `append_fields` function in `numpy.lib.recfunctions` won't let me add an array of objects.

Here's some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfun

dtype= np.dtype([('WIND_WAVE_HGHT', '<f4'), ('WIND_WAVE_PERD', '<f4')])
obs = np.array([(0.1,10.0),(0.2,11.0),(0.3,12.0)], dtype=dtype)

dates = np.array([datetime.datetime(2001,1,1,0),
    datetime.datetime(2001,1,1,0),
    datetime.datetime(2001,1,1,0)])

# This doesn't work:
recfun.append_fields(obs,'obdate',dates,dtypes=np.object)
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.`

It seems to only be an issue with np.object arrays as I can append other fields ok. Am I missing something?

Comment: `obs` was first an empty recarray, then a list.  That's not how you add values to a recarray.  For the append field have you considered `np.datetime64`?

Comment: @hpaulj Oops - my mistake; have fixed the obs array initialisation. I can't use `np.datetime64` as this is part of a larger codeset that expects `datetime` objects

Comment: What's dtype ot dates

Comment: @hpaulj `dates` has dtype of `np.object`

Comment: I'd have to examine the code of the function.  Or it may be simpler to make your own `out` array, and copy fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

```
In [143]: recfun.append_fields(obs,'test',np.array([None,[],1]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-5c3de23b09f7> in <module>()
----> 1 recfun.append_fields(obs,'test',np.array([None,[],1]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py in append_fields(base, names, data, dtypes, fill_value, usemask, asrecarray)
    615     if dtypes is None:
    616         data = [np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True) for a in data]
--> 617         data = [a.view([(name, a.dtype)]) for (name, a) in zip(names, data)]
    618     else:
    619         if not isinstance(dtypes, (tuple, list)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    615     if dtypes is None:
    616         data = [np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True) for a in data]
--> 617         data = [a.view([(name, a.dtype)]) for (name, a) in zip(names, data)]
    618     else:
    619         if not isinstance(dtypes, (tuple, list)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py in _view_is_safe(oldtype, newtype)
    363 
    364     if newtype.hasobject or oldtype.hasobject:
--> 365         raise TypeError("Cannot change data-type for object array.")
    366     return
    367 

TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

So the problem is in this `a.view([(name, a.dtype)])` expression.  It tries to make a single field structured array from `a`.  That works with dtypes like int and str, but fails with `object`.  That failure is in the core `view` handling, so isn't likely to change.

```
In [148]: x=np.arange(3)

In [149]: x.view([('test', x.dtype)])
Out[149]: 
array([(0,), (1,), (2,)], 
      dtype=[('test', '<i4')])

In [150]: x=np.array(['one','two'])

In [151]: x.view([('test', x.dtype)])
Out[151]: 
array([('one',), ('two',)], 
      dtype=[('test', '<U3')])

In [152]: x=np.array([[1],[1,2]])

In [153]: x
Out[153]: array([[1], [1, 2]], dtype=object)

In [154]: x.view([('test', x.dtype)])
...
TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

The fact that `recfunctions` requires a separate load indicates that it is somewhat of a backwater, that isn't used a lot, and not under active development.  I haven't examined the code in detail, but I suspect a fix would be a kludge.

### A fix

Here's a way of adding a new field from scratch.  It performs the same basic actions as `append_fields`:

Define a new dtype, using the `obs` and the new field name and dtype:

```
In [158]: obs.dtype.descr
Out[158]: [('WIND_WAVE_HGHT', '<f4'), ('WIND_WAVE_PERD', '<f4')]

In [159]: obs.dtype.descr+[('TEST',object)]
Out[159]: [('WIND_WAVE_HGHT', '<f4'), ('WIND_WAVE_PERD', '<f4'), ('TEST', object)]

In [160]: dt1  =np.dtype(obs.dtype.descr+[('TEST',object)])
```

Make an empty target array, and fill it by copying data by field name:

```
In [161]: newobs = np.empty(obs.shape, dtype=dt1)    
In [162]: for n in obs.dtype.names:
     ...:     newobs[n]=obs[n]

In [167]: dates
Out[167]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0)], dtype=object)

In [168]: newobs['TEST']=dates

In [169]: newobs
Out[169]: 
array([( 0.1       ,  10., datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
       ( 0.2       ,  11., datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
       ( 0.30000001,  12., datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0))], 
      dtype=[('WIND_WAVE_HGHT', '<f4'), ('WIND_WAVE_PERD', '<f4'), ('TEST', 'O')])
```

### datetime64 alternative

With the native numpy datetimes, append works

```
In [179]: dates64 = dates.astype('datetime64[D]')

In [180]: recfun.append_fields(obs,'test',dates64,usemask=False)
Out[180]: 
array([( 0.1       ,  10., '2001-01-01'),
       ( 0.2       ,  11., '2001-01-01'), ( 0.30000001,  12., '2001-01-01')], 
      dtype=[('WIND_WAVE_HGHT', '<f4'), ('WIND_WAVE_PERD', '<f4'), ('test', '<M8[D]')])
```

`append_fields` has some bells-n-whistles that my version doesn't - fill values, masked arrays, recarray, etc.

### structured dates array

I could create a structured array with the dates

```
In [197]: sdates = np.array([(i,) for i in dates],dtype=[('test',object)])
In [198]: sdates
Out[198]: 
array([(datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),),
       (datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),),
       (datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),)], 
      dtype=[('test', 'O')])
```

There must be a function that merges fields of existing arrays, but I'm not finding it.

### previous work

This felt familiar:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2346

[TypeError when appending fields to a structured array of size ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36440557/typeerror-when-appending-fields-to-a-structured-array-of-size-one)

[Adding datetime field to recarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739733/adding-datetime-field-to-recarray)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. It feels like there is still some functionality in `numpy` that needs a bit of bug fixing/finessing! I will probably go along with your second suggestion and build a new array....it's probably what `append_fields` does in the background anyhow :)